# How to handle custom proxy authentication

Tags: c#, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid

A third party wants us to connect to their services via one of their proxies. However, instead of a VPN they want us to use a web-based proxy such as

https://public.thirdparty.com/proxy.ashx?url=https://secret.thirdparty.com/services/

That in itself I don't believe to be too hard to solve but they have an additional level of security in that the proxy itself requires a custom **Authorization** header equal to

`GMT timestamp in format yyyyMMddHHmmssffff + ':' + Base64(HMAC-SHA256(ConvertToUTF8(Proxy Url + '\n' + Service Url + '\n' + secret)))`

This authorization header is valid only for 180 seconds, and because it includes the requesting service url has to be generated for every url. The POST or GET parameters don't seem to be needed to be encoded.

We cannot accomodate this requirement in code (C#) because the library we are using to execute operations on these services gives us no access to the direct HTTP request it creates so we cannot append a Authorization header.

So we must use some sort of middleware proxy that will allow us to make a simple request to our proxy like

https://ourproxy.com/services/this/is/myrequest

and in turn directs that to

https://public.thirdparty.com/proxy.ashx?url=https://secret.thirdparty.com/services/this/is/myrequest

and adds the special authorization header to the request.

---

I am thinking a proxy server like squid may have the ability to do something like this but I fear only if a custom module is written (in C language) and its not just a configuration or script we can write.

I am looking for advice on how to accomplish our needs, from suggesting software that could do it to even suggesting a community/service that will write it for us for a price.